# Export both Image and Data from R to an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: r, excel

It is simple to print an image and save it on disk just:

```
fit <- lm(some ~ model)

png(filename="your/file/location/name.png")
plot(fit)
dev.off()
```

Write some data to a excel spreadsheet just

```
write.csv(rnorm(10),"some file",sep=",")
```

My question is how would one redirect both the above in to a spreadsheet. Another word, output a graph paired withs some image/plot on to a excel workbook?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use the `xlsx` package. Check out the `addPicture` function and the `addDataFrame` function. I found this package fairly easy to work with.

Answer (score 9):

You can do the same thing with the `insertImage` function and using the `openxlsx` package.

I've copied the example from above, but using the openxlsx package instead:

```
# Setup
x <- c('tidyverse', 'openxlsx')
sapply(X=x, FUN = require, character.only = TRUE)

# Create graph---------
dcs <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(cyl, disp))

# Export Pic -----------
pic_path <- "C:/home/dcs.jpeg"
png(filename = pic_path)
plot(dcs)
dev.off()

# Add to a new work book -------------
wb <- openxlsx::createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Plots")
insertImage(wb, "Plots", pic_path)
openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wb,
                       "~/example.xlsx")

# Kill pic
unlink(pic_path)
```

Comment: Best solution for me, openxlsx doesn't require rJava package, which is problematic.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add an example about the xlsx package, as far as i can tell it requires you to first save the picture, then import it to the xlsx file, see a reproducible example of exporting to an existing book below:

```
# Setup
x <- c('tidyverse', 'rJava', 'xlsxjars', 'xlsx')
sapply(X=x, FUN = require, character.only = TRUE)

# Create graph---------
dcs <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(cyl, disp))

# Export Pic -----------
pic_path <- "C:/home/dcs.jpeg"
png(filename = pic_path)
plot(dcs)
dev.off()

# Add to existing book -------------
xl_path <- "C:/home/a.xlsx"

wb <- loadWorkbook(xl_path)

ws <- getSheets(wb)["Summary"][[1]]

addPicture(file = pic_path, sheet = ws)

saveWorkbook(wb, xl_path)

# Kill pic
unlink(pic_path)

#Then write some data
write.xlsx(as.data.frame(output), xl_path, sheetName = 'data'))
```