# R script to insert images into Google Sheets

Tags: r, google-sheets, r-googlesheets

Is there a way to insert images, in this case ggplot2 charts, into a Google Sheet, using an R script?  Maybe using the `googlesheets` package?

I see how to [add an image to an *Excel* spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976522/export-both-image-and-data-from-r-to-an-excel-spreadsheet) and I can add an image to a Google Sheet in my browser via *Insert* -> *Image* in the Sheets menus.  But I'd like to add the image to my sheet from within an R script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, and it seems the image will take exactly the size of one cell by default. But it is a *way to insert images*:

```
x <- gs_edit_cells(ss=x, ws="y", input='=IMAGE("https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrDZc.jpg")')
```

You can then manually from within Google Sheets resize the cell and thus the image as well.

Of course the new problem is now how to give an image a web-address from within R --- but I wouldn't think that is too hard.

Comment: This worked!  And actually the `IMAGE()` function takes values for `mode`, `height`, and `width` so you can insert the image at the size you want.  E.g., `x <- gs_edit_cells(ss=x, ws="y", input='=IMAGE("https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrDZc.jpg", 4, 800, 1200)')`