# Upload an image from disk to Google sheets through API (preferably googlesheets4 package)

Tags: r, google-sheets, google-api, googlesheets4

I want to upload an image to existing Google spreadsheets through Google's API. However, I a) haven#t been able to figure out how nor b) if there's even a more or less "easy" way of doing it.

Among others, I looked e.g. at: [Insert image into Google Sheets cell using Google Sheets API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664483/insert-image-into-google-sheets-cell-using-google-sheets-api) or [R script to insert images into Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50182634/r-script-to-insert-images-into-google-sheets)

Also looking at `?googlesheets::gs4_formula` indicate that adding images is generally possible. However, it looks like this can only be done for web images.

**Is there any way to upload images from a) disk or b) plotted objects within R to an existing google sheet through R?**

More specifically:

- Is there a dedicated APi endpoint or would be the existing ones do the trick?
- Is it possible to define a file path instead of a web path in the IMAGE function of Gsheets?

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: No. The only workaround that, well, works, is to put an image into an Excel file and then ipload the whole Excel file sheet. But that of course requires that you already have all the info in your Wxcel sheet that you want to have in your gsheet. Adding an image to an existing gsheet is not doable. Only the other way around: uploading Excel with image, convert to gsheet, add other content to gsheet. Very unnecessary and stupid restriction from the gsheets API.

Comment: Thanks - thought so. I am actually looking at converting my sheets to some kind of reports with pictures (might even be more readable).