# How to save graph(plotly) in excel(any format png,jpeg..etc)?

Tags: r, plotly, xlsx

I have created the plot via plotly. would like to save my graph in excel.
any lead will be much appreciated.

I tried below code which can save graph in html.but this is not something which i am looking.

`htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(p22), "Output_Graph.html")`

Comment: Step1: Find out how to output as plotly object as jpeg image, Step2 see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17976522/680068

Comment: Thanks but not work out for me. as I have seen this answer but in my case output of graph from ```plotly```. in this example they have done with ```ggplot```.

Comment: @TusharLad Are you meaning to say that you would like plotly to work with full interactive flexibilty ***in*** Excel?

Comment: @vestland, not sure but if is there a solution available in community will be useful for any one like me.this thought came in my mind because when we share some tabular data then if we can share graph in excel will be useful to analyze data easily.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this :

```
library(pagedown)
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(p22), "Output_Graph.html")
chrome_print("Output_Graph.html", output = "Output_Graph.png")
```

With chrome_print, we can print a local html file to PDF, PNG or JPEG. Once, the graph is in PNG, you can include it in your Excel file.