# How to append an R plot to a given column in a csv file?

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, append, export-to-csv

I know how to append "say numbers" to a csv file using R. What I want is to paste the respective graphs also for the same file in the respective column. Here's the code I tried, but failed.
Please help.

```
library(muhaz)
library(readr)

ball_data <- read_csv("C:/Users/dovini jayasinghe/Desktop/Cricket/ball data.csv")

attach(ball_data)
#View(ball_data)

for(i in 1:3){
  fit <- muhaz(times = scoreValue[help_index2==i], 
               delta = Censored[help_index2==i], 
               bw.method="local", 
               kern="epanechnikov", 
               max.time=max(scoreValue[help_index2==i]))
  
  graph <- plot(fit)#draws the plot
  
  max_x <- max(fit$pin$times)
  
  #data frame excluding the graph
  df <- data.frame("Ball Number" = i,
                   "Maximum Score" = max_x
                   )
  
  #if we need the graph, I think the code is this way
  # df <- data.frame("Ball Number" = i,
  #                  "Maximum Score" = max_x,
  #                  "Graph" = graph)
  
  
  write.table(df,
              'C://Users//dovini jayasinghe//Desktop//Cricket//hazard_i_th_ball.csv',
              row.names = FALSE,
              col.names = FALSE,
              sep = ",",
              append = TRUE)
}
```

To be specific, I need a table (a csv file) like this

| Ball Number | Maximum Score | Graph |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | image of the plot 1 |
| 2 | 1 | image of the plot 2 |
| 3 | 3 | image of the plot 3 |

Comment: I read CSV, and don't think that is possible - but if you mean more broadly, a spreadsheet - it is possible to add an image to an XLSX Excel spreadsheet. https://stackoverflow.com/q/17976522/10276092

Comment: Indeed, `csv` is a "flat" file, i.e. you can store symbols (i.e. characters, numbers, and some special symbols) in it. This excludes "objects" like an image. What you could do is save the code (:= text) for the image. Alternatively, you can store your table in a `html` file/page and have the image in your 3rd column.